# How wire a 3-way motion sensor switch when replacing one of the 3-way toggle switches (with load between the switches)

Tags: wiring, multiway-switch, motion-sensor

I have a 3-way light circuit in a basement stairwell controlled by two 3-way toggle switches (the load is between the switches).

I want to replace one of the toggle switches with a 3-way motion sensor switch, but the instructions that came with the 3-way motion sensor switch only show how to wire the two switches if the circuit is a "typical 3-way application".  There is no information about how to wire the switches when the load is between the switches.

I can't find any videos or wiring diagrams online that describe a 3-way circuit controlled by one 3-way motion sensor switch and one 3-way toggle switch when the load is between the two switches.

Comment: Does the power come into the light, or into one of the switches? Do the two /3+gnd cables both go through the light i.e. stop there and are spliced?

Comment: If you post a picture, with a color of the wires, it would help us

Comment: If you include the brand/model of the new switch, and maybe even a link to the instructions for it that would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 1):

The *usual* ways to wire 3-way circuits are:

- panel -> load -> switch 1 -> switch 2

or

- panel -> switch 1 -> switch 2 -> load

There *are* other ways where the load could possibly be truly "in between" the switches. But normally even if the load *appears* to be in between, the wiring follows one of the above patterns.

The key for a modern motion sensor/switch, timer, etc. is *neutral*. There are ways to make these things work without neutral, but they generally don't work well with LED lighting. The comment about a 4th blue wire in the new switch implies that it also has black, red and white. The usual setup (check the instructions) would then be:

- black = incoming hot
- red = switched hot or traveler 1
- blue = traveler 2, if needed
- white = neutral

Check your existing switch boxes to see how things are wired. If you have the first pattern and an older house then you probably do *not* have neutral at either switch. **White is not always neutral, especially on 3-way switch circuits!** If you have the second pattern then you should have neutral at both switches, but the new switch will only work as "switch 1" because it needs incoming hot and switch 2 will have 2 travelers coming in, neutral bypassing and switched hot going out.

Pictures showing the existing wiring can help us confirm what you have and exactly what to do.